# Java Mail over TLS

Tags: java, email, ssl

I am trying to send an email from my program through a TLS connection. Here is my code

```
    final String username = "XXXXXX";
    final String password = "XXXXX"; 
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "mail.xxxx.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
              protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                  return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
              }
            });

    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("from@xxxx.com"));
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
        InternetAddress.parse(to_address));
    message.setSubject("Test Mail"); 
    message.setText("TestMail ");
    Transport.send(message)
```

My email gateway has incoming Mail settings with SSL enabled and outgoing with TLS enabled on port 587. I am able to configure this settings in outlook and it's working fine. But through my java program it's saying "Connection Refused".
Help Appreciated!

## Worked Finally:

I used the [InstallCert](http://kenai.com/projects/javamail/pages/InstallCert) program to import the certicate to generate jssecacerts file and I added the file to my /jre/lib/security/ path. here is my working code

```
    properties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "XXXXXX");  
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "465"); 
    properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", true);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false"); 
    properties.put("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false"); 
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
```

Comment: In this case you just got to importing a certificate from a specific server? I have the same problem, but my application needs to send mail from any account configured by the user, the code works with Outlook, Google and Yahoo, but for an account with smtp zimbra.xxxxxxx.net.br not work because of this certificate.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the `smtps` protocol instead of `smtp`

```
props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtps");
props.put("mail.smtps.starttls.enable","true");
props.put("mail.smtps.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtps.host", "mail.xxxx.com");
props.put("mail.smtps.port", "587");
```

You can also try to set the protocol specificly for rfc822, this helps some times

```
props.put("mail.transport.protocol.rfc822", "smtps");
```

Comment: I tried this still same issue...this time it's trying to connect "localhost" , port 25 .this is my debug log ....                     DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "localhost", port 25, isSSL false

Comment: What version of javamail are you using ?

Comment: props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtps");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "mail.xxxxx.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");                                     Getting "Connection refused" ....

Comment: connection refused on the correct port ? (what the JavaMail debug say its connecting to) SMTPS are usually 465 not 587 (Which is usually IMAP)

Comment: No. I tested with outlook. OUtgoing mails with 587 + TLS working fine but not 465.

Comment: If the problem is connection refused then the host/port is not correct, please verify that. if you were trying to use regular smtp with smtps server you would get a different error

Comment: Got it worked finally..Just modified my question. Thanks lot for your support Aviram!