# javax.mail unable to send mail to hotmail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send mails using `javax.mail` from an *hotmail account*.
Until now I've tested my code also using *gmail account* and everything works fine, but
with hotmail nothing works in particular, I receive a `MailConnectException`.
This is the code that I use in order to send the mail:

```
props.put("mail.starttls.enable", true);
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.live.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
props.put("mail.debug", true);
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
```

As you can see I've created a PropertiesFactory in order to create a specific instance of the Properties object for each specific mail host that I use. In the code there is the factory for the HotmailProperties structure.

Starting a debugging session I've checked that useAuth option and isSSL are both equal to false.
What do I change in the properties configuration? Maybe there are some other errors in the code?

This is the debugging result of my program:
http://ideone.com/SDu4JG

**SOLVED**
I've solved my problem with the hotmail server.
Looking to this page: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/outlook/send-receive-from-app
I've understood that hotmail, differently from the other mail servers like gmail and yahoo, considers the username as the complete email address. So when I do the login I always receive an error.

Finally it works. Thank you to all.

Comment: Stack trace of exception please?

Comment: http://ideone.com/9g9JCn
This is what I got when I execute the program.

Comment: props.put("mail.smtps.port", "487"); ?

Comment: Is the port incorrect? don't I use "mail.smtp.port"?

Comment: If the port is correct you have to look up at help sites of hotmail,. But your debug messages are saying that the host is responding with *530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first* so the port should be correct. The properties are named false at configuration, I'm quite sure ;)

Comment: But how can I fix it? The properties that I use was configured in the way that I've written and the starttls command was done.
During the execution of the program I've printed the content of the properties object and this is the result:
    STRUCT: {mail.starttls.enable=true, mail.smtp.user=alexanderforzamola, mail.debug=true, mail.smtp.port=25, mail.smtp.pass=xxxxx, mail.smtp.auth=true, mail.smtp.host=smtp.live.com}

Answer (score 1):

It's Working for me . Surely it will work for u 
:--

with port 587:--

```
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");   
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.live.com");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");   
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");  
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

    Session smtpSession = Session.getInstance(props1, authenticator);
        smtpSession.setDebug(true);
```

Comment: may be problem in authentication . i maintain session from last two lines & its working for me

Comment: good :) so post the answer for others can gain effort, too :)

Answer (score 1):

From your debug output:

```
MAIL FROM:<shadowtemplate@hotmail.com>
530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first
DEBUG SMTP: got response code 530, with response: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first
```

Status code 530 means that the client was not authenticated. (I googled "SMTP error status code 530" to get this)

Your message above indicates that TLS (transport layer security: encryption) is required

Apparently, Hotmail requires that you send mail over smtps and the default port is 587.

Comment: DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.0
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.live.com", port 587, isSSL true

This is what I got using as protocol smtps

Answer (score 0):

You named the properties mail.smtp**s** instead of mail.smtp

There is already a question which is solved, have a look: [Java Mail over TLS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13834768/java-mail-over-tls)

Comment: But this kind of operation should enable it.
Or not?

Comment: Yes it does (I'd understand you don't want to use it). In this case you have to set the authentication credentials (username/passwort) in addition, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: props.put("mail.starttls.enable", true);
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.live.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
props.put("mail.debug", true);
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);

Should I use this configuration? Is it enough?

Comment: that and *props.put("mail.smtp.user", "USERNAME");* and 
*props.put("mail.password", "PASSWORD");*

Comment: the protocol is smtp and not smtps?

Comment: good question without knowing your code. Please edit your question while adding two things: the resulting stack trace you're resolving and the complete block of Java code used to configure and send the mail

Comment: SMTPS is an underlying protocol at the transport layer and is completely independent. Further the protocol name has nothing to do with the properties! Java Mail uses SMTP in the background, but the property names remain like they are: *mail.smtp.*

Comment: You can check my code in the ideone link.
Also I've edited the message adding to it the debugging result of the program execution.

Comment: sorry, I've overred it. Change the property names at configuration (remove the s from smtps) and try again

Comment: I've tried without the 's' but I receive the same error. the isSSL value is still false.

Comment: sorry, now i have to do other things, too. Have a look at the question I've updated in my answer and compare the codes. Good Luck ;)

Comment: But, as I've said before, I don't have problems with gmail. So this is only an incorrect configuration for hotmail.