# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException when trying to send email with JavaMail SMTP

Tags: java, email, ssl, smtp, jakarta-mail

I have looked at the other similar questions which recommended adding `properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");` which still didn't work for me. I also saw some answers recommending commenting out `properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");`
which also didn't work for me. I have no antivirus other than the default windows one and no other special program; why is this happening?

**Code**

```
 public static void sendMail(String recipient) throws MessagingException {
        System.out.println("Preparing to send email...");
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        String myAccountEmail = "alexfarts05@gmail.com";
        String myAccountPassword = "alexIsFarting!";

        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(myAccountEmail, myAccountPassword);
            }
        });
        Message message = prepareMessage(session, myAccountEmail, recipient);
        Transport.send(message);
        System.out.println("Email sent!");
    }
    private static Message prepareMessage(Session session, String myAccountEmail, String recipient) {
        try {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(myAccountEmail));
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipient));
            message.setSubject("Hello, this is a test email!");
            message.setText("Big strong men");
            return message;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SendMail.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**Full Error**

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:1907)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:666)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:253)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at SendMail.sendMail(SendMail.java:33)
    at Main.main(Main.java:5)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.<init>(HandshakeContext.java:172)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshakeContext.<init>(ClientHandshakeContext.java:103)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.kickstart(TransportContext.java:239)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:443)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:421)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:527)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.startTLS(SocketFetcher.java:464)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:1902)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `props.put("properties.transport.protocol", "smtps")` and replacing `smtp` to `smtps`?

Comment: yes I get a `Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25;` error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13834822/4655217

Comment: yes i copied that exactly and I still get the error `javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution, adding this line `properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.2"` to the properties, as well as creating an [app password](https://myaccount.google.com/u/2/apppasswords) for the google account you are using fixes it. You need to enable 2FA on the account and then use the created password in your program

**Complete final properties**

```
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
```